# Is is possible to make a cross domain POST ajax request of application/json?

Tags: jquery, http, cross-domain, csrf, cors

I am testing some csrf stuff, and I am wondering if it is possible to POST a cross domain ajax request with `Content-Type: application/json`

Every time I try to do this with jQuery:

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "http://someotherdomain.com/endpoint",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    data: {"a": "1"},
    dataType: "json",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(data){ alert(data); }, 
    failure: function(data){ alert(data); }
  });
```

I always send **HTTP OPTIONS** requests instead of **HTTP POSTs**.

Note- that I don't care about receiving data back, a one way post is all I need.

Note- that the content-type can't be `x-www-form-urlencoded` and it can't be a GET request either.

Answer (score 4):

The `Content-Type: application/json` header is not a simple header, and therefore first requires a preflight request before the actual request. The HTTP OPTIONS request you are seeing is the preflight request. From the CORS spec (http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/):

> A header is said to be a simple header if the header field name is an
>   ASCII case-insensitive match for Accept, Accept-Language, or
>   Content-Language, or if it is an ASCII case-insensitive match for
>   Content-Type and the header field value media type (excluding
>   parameters) is an ASCII case-insensitive match for
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain.

In order to get past the preflight request, the server needs to respond to the OPTIONS request with the following headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
```

Once the browser receives this response, it will make the actual HTTP POST request. Note that if your request contains additional custom headers, you will need to include them in the Access-Control-Allow-Headers response header.  You can learn more about CORS preflight requests here:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/#toc-adding-cors-support-to-the-server

Comment: Great answer, a subtle point that's often overlooked. I wonder how GET text/plain is allowed to bypass CORS when GET application/json isn't. Is there a simple/elegant/largely-supported way to receive JSON with content-type plain/text in the request?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible if your browser supports so called Cross-Origin Resource Sharing ([CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)), and [all modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=CORS), support this nowadays. In short, server should provide you `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Also, regarding the fact that, as you've said, you does not bother about getting any information as response, why don't you just submit some form?

Comment: The server only accepts application/json requests, and I don't have control of the server. So I can't have the server provide any headers nor submit a form. Is there any other options?

Comment: @JarrodEverett, then it look like that CORS is the best solution, if only, of course, server can return such header. Otherwise I'd advice to have a proxy on your side which adds that header. But the thing is - if you have proxy, you don't have to thing about these cross domain issues )))

Comment: is this possible to do with flash perhaps?

Comment: don't know action script to that extent, but I doubt. any way, even if it possible, from javascript point it would be another sort of proxy, and not the best one.