# contentType: 'application/json' with POST method (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services, http-headers

I need to create a web server client in JavaScript and I have some problems to define Request headers.

I need POST method and Content-Type: "application/json".

I tried this:

```
    $.ajax({
            url: 'http://MyWebServiceAddress',
            data: JSON.stringify({user:'user',pass:'pass'}),
            type: 'POST',
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function () {
                    alert("success")
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert("Error: " + xhr.status + "\n" +
                        "Message: " + xhr.statusText + "\n" +
                        "Response: " + xhr.responseText + "\n" + thrownError);
            }
        });
```

But if I put contentType like this:

> contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

and look then the request with Chrome Dev Tools I can see that method was changed to "OPTIONS" and type to "text/plain"

Anyone can help me? I don't have to use Ajax, so if someone know a good JavaScript library to make client easier, maybe can result my problems

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12132760/is-is-possible-to-make-a-cross-domain-post-ajax-request-of-application-json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do need to set the `contentType` header just as you've written; the `contentType` is for the request itself, while the `dataType` header is for the response you're expecting back from the server. So if you add that `contentType` to the `$.ajax` request, it looks correct.

The "OPTIONS" request is a different issue: that's being sent because you must be making a "cross-origin" request, meaning the ajax request's service address (`http://MyWebServiceAddress`) is different from the current page's "origin" address. Is that the case? An example would be if your page comes from `http://example.com`, and you are making a request to `http://twitter.com` from that page. You can read more about cross-origin, or CORS, requests [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/). The bottom line is that `$.ajax` has to make a separate ORIGIN request before posting JSON data like you're doing, and then it will make the POST request -- *if and only if* the server at `http://MyWebServiceAddress` is configured to allow CORS requests from your page's domain. See that CORS link above for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Cross domain requests are subject to the [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

They [require permission from the server](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) to:

- Read the data from the response
- Make some kind of requests in the first place

You have triggered one the latter conditions, so the browser is making a [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) using the OPTIONS verb.

The server needs to respond with CORS headers granting permission.

Something like:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://your.server.example.com
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
```

… should do the job (untested).

When the browser gets the response, it will then make the POST request.