# Adding the contentType: "application/json" make error

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, iis, cors, contenttype

I want to have a service that calls from an HTML file. for example like this:

```
// POST api/values
public ActionResult Post([FromBody]Models.FormEntry[] composit)
{
    //Some Code here ...

    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(200);
}
```

then I call this service from an HTML file like below:

```
<script>
    function onSubmit(form) {
        var data = $(form).serializeArray();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:45407/api/values",
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                dataType: "text",
                //contentType: "application/json",
                success: function () { alert('YES!'); },
                error: function () { alert('NO NO NO!'); }});
    }
</script>
```

its behave nomally but sending nothing to service, and the `composit` argument gives null value. when I Uncomment the `contentType: "application/json"` it makes error and service doesn't call.
I test it by the postman (Chrome extension) and it works perfectly. the postman recommends me this code:

```
var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "http://localhost:45407/api/values",
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
        "postman-token": "e1b9721b-2925-c413-69e0-b1b21de239cb"
      },
      "processData": false,
      "data": data
    }

    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
          console.log(response);
    });
```

I replace above code with mine, but the service call still has an unknown error. I think it is maybe a security consideration, that we not allow to sent requests from `localhost`, for this reson I add `<httpProtocol>` under the `<system.webServer>` tag in service web.config file like this:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
  <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
  <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE" />
  <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, soapaction" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

for this problem, I saw this links:

- [contentType: 'application/json' with POST method (JavaScript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22531166/contenttype-application-json-with-post-method-javascript)
- [Jquery JQGrid breaks when contentType=application/json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845494/jquery-jqgrid-breaks-when-contenttype-application-json)
- [AJAX POST call with application/json contentType gets “no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header” error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42694651/ajax-post-call-with-application-json-contenttype-gets-no-access-control-allow)

So how can I call a Restful service from an HTML file and sent a JSON array in the request body, by setting a true Content Type?

Answer (score 2):

Adding the `content-type: application/json` request header triggers your browser to do a CORS preflight `OPTIONS` request.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS has more details.

> So how can I call a Restful service from an HTML file and sent a JSON array in the request body, by setting a true Content Type?

You need to configure the server for the `http://localhost:45407/api/values` endpoint to send an `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` response header that includes `Content-Type` in its value.

Exactly how you do that depends on what particular server backend `http://localhost:45407` is running. But regardless, it needs to be configured on that server. You can’t do it from the client side.

Comment: thank you,  according to my description, I add `<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />` to my web.config, is your mean to add `<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE" />` and `<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, content-type, Accept" />` to web.config too?

Comment: Yes. If you add those settings for `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` in the same place where you have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` already set, then the CORS preflight OPTIONS request should succeed, and so your browser will move on to doing the POST as expected (and the browser will allow your frontend JavaScript code to access the response from that)

Comment: I add the options under the `<httpProtocol>` in service web.config, like this: `<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE" />` and `<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />` , but it's not work! when I remove the header options in service call request, it works but sends null value to the service. is my syntax correct? or where I placed them is correct?

Comment: I don’t personally have much insight and experience to offer as fas as IIS config, so if it’s not working I think you might want to post a new separate specific question about that, and tag it with [iis] or [asp.net-mvc] or whatever—so that the people here who do have specific expertise in those can give you more expert help

Answer (score 0):

Sending Headers to the browser is the work of a server. An ajax call is a client request. You need not to send header on it. In fact, you can return type can be 'json'. You need not serializeArray, serialize function will work

A short form of post request is as follows:

```
$.post('http://localhost:45407/api/values',
    $('#formId').serialize(), function(response){
         //callback body
    }, 'json');
```

Now on the server side , you need some changes
before sending the response set the header 'application/json'
if this is a cross domain request ajax call will not work. You will have to whitelist the request domain.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

You can use any particular url instead of using "*". This wildcard character actually allowing all request to be valid if they are coming from outside the domain the resource exists.

Comment: according to my descriptions, I add this header option before in the service web.config. did you mean, I must place that in the else where?